# Issues with Socket.IO (>= 1.0) and Bouncy

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, socket.io

There seems to be some incompatibilities between Socket.IO and Bouncy : in Chrome and Firefox (not in Edge), my browser tabs hang when I open more than 5.

I know it's caused by the NPM module "Bouncy" because if I remove the code that uses it, everything works fine and there's no limit to how many browser tabs I can open. The other culprit is the new version of Socket.IO (>= 1.0, which I just updated to), because when I downgrade back to v0.9.16 the problem goes away as well.

Here's some relevant server code :

```
var port = 8502;
var bouncy = require('bouncy');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require("express");
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);
server.listen(port);

var serverBouncer = bouncy(function(req, res, bounce) {
    var path = req.url;
    var url = req.headers.host;
    if (typeof url !== "string") {
      res.send(500);
      res.end();
      return;
    }
    var urlArray = url.split('.');
    var bouncePort = port;
    if (!isNaN(urlArray[0]))
        bouncePort = parseInt(urlArray[0]);
    else if (String(urlArray[0]).toLowerCase() === "www" && !isNaN(urlArray[1]))
        bouncePort = parseInt(urlArray[1]);
    bounce(bouncePort);
});
serverBouncer.listen(80);


io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    //Some events...
});
```

Here's some relevant client code :

```
var client = io.connect();
```

I have been stuck trying to solve this problem for the past 3 days, any help is immensely appreciated.

---

**Update:**
Here's what the network tab of chrome dev tools looks like :

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

I changed the config of socket.io (server side) to force websocket :

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'polling']);
```

Same for the client side :

```
var client = io({transports: ['websocket', 'polling']});
```

But now the events I emit don't reach the server. Here's what the network tab looks like :

[image]

---

**Update 3:**
Versions of the main components :

- NodeJS v6.2.2
- Socket.IO v1.4.8
- Bouncy v3.2.2
- Cors v2.7.1
- Express v4.14.0
- Npm v3.10.5

Comment: What port are your socket.io connections coming in on?  socket.io connections start out as an http request so you will have to make sure that bouncy is reliably forwarding those to the socket.io server.  One difference between socket.io before and after 1.0 is that the newest socket.io will often send a few messages with just plain http requests before it has established that webSocket is working and then it switches over to webSocket.

Comment: Socket.io is bound to the app which is listening on port 8502. The bouncy server is listening on port 80. What boggles my mind is that it works fine for 5 browser tabs and then starts having trouble afterwards... Downgrading socket.io or removing bouncy solves the problem, but I don't want to do either of these things.

Comment: The reason behind the bouncy server is to be able to redirect clients to other apps running on other ports with URLs such as 5555.domain.com, without having to open ports on the machine running the server.

Comment: I'd suggest you look in the network tab in the browser and see what's going on with each connection when things fail.  I'm guessing that your server infrastructure may not be responding to some requests properly and thus the browser runs out of connections to your domain until those requests finally timeout.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks a lot for your input, I added a screenshot of the network tab, not exactly sure what's going on. Mind having a look?

Comment: A bad request and a couple other connections that haven't yet responded looks like something is wrong.  There are issues filed in the bouncy Github repository about socket.io compatibility when using xhr polling.  I can't tell if they are all fixed or not in the latest version.  You would probably bypass the issue if you have the client force webSocket connection and never use xhr polling.  In socket.io 1.0, the default changed to start with xhr polling and only after several exchanges, switch to websocket.  It appears that xhr polling is where the issue is.

Comment: Again, thanks for your input, feels great to get some help with this. I updated the OP!

Comment: Why are you still allowing polling?  It looks like your webSocket connections are getting dropped and then re-established.

Comment: I tried with simply `['websockets']` but it's giving the same results. We have some users that use browsers that do not support websockets, so I'd like to keep polling as an option.

Comment: I meant `['websocket']`

Comment: Not much else I can do without having actual code in front of me to run tests on and debug.  What version of node.js are you running?

Comment: Node v6.2.2 (with socket.io v1.4.8). Don't worry, I value your time and efforts very much... Not sure if I'm forcing the transports the right way. According to the docs, it seems like it should work this way. Maybe I should specify a URL to connect? Default was working in socket.io < 1.0.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but never just `return` in a request handler: always send back a response (a 400 or 500 error). Some random tidbits: even with websockets as only transport, `socket.io` (or rather `engine.io`, which it uses under the hood) will initially use polling to set up the connection. Because of what seem to be stuck XHR requests, the amount of concurrent connections from your browser to your host will reach the browser-imposed maximum (which usually is around 6), blocking any further requests. I'd focus on finding out why the XHR requests are failing.

Comment: Good point @robertklep, thanks for pointing it out. I fixed that, but as you suspected, it was not the issue. I read about the browser-imposed max but I find it rather weird that it only kicks in when I use both the new version of socket.IO AND the bouncy server, as removing any of those 2 actually solves the problem (but leaves me with disabled important functionalities). I've been researching the failed XHR requests but still haven't found anything useful/related to my problem... :(

Comment: @BernardSaucier because the XHR requests get stuck (for whatever reason), the limit gets reached, which amplifies the issue even more. Since v1 changed the way it sets up the initial connection, it may be that you're running into a bad interaction between socket.io and bouncy. I just noticed that your Express app is running on a different port (8502) than the proxy (80). How exactly are those two tied together? Can it happen that the socket.io setup requests are mistakenly being proxied?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, it's definitely a bad interaction between the two modules. Indeed, the Express and Bouncy are running on different ports: the Bouncy server receives the HTTP request on port 80 and forwards it to 8502 if there is no number prefixing the URL. In case of a port prefixing the URL, the request gets forwarded to that specific port (for example, 5555.domain.com goes through port 80 and is internally forwarded to port 5555). Not sure how I can setup socket.io differently to avoid bouncy.

Comment: @BernardSaucier I set up a test app ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/15e5610724e26618adaf70eeff7b66c2)), it looks like bouncy is preventing `socket.io` from creating a websocket connection, so it falls back to polling. This makes things fall apart real fast (for me as well). I think that using `bouncy` is going to be a lost cause; `node-http-proxy` has websocket support so may work better (although I believe that it didn't work really well either?). Or perhaps you should run the `socket.io` part of your server on port 80 as well, instead of 8502.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your time and effort, I truly appreciate it. I'll try to bind socket io to the bouncy server instead of the node server. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Socket.IO doesn't want to bind to the bouncy server. I'm looking into setting up nginx to take care of the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replace the bouncy module with nginx. See my other question for the solution.

[nginx : redirect to port according to domain prefix (dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808860/nginx-redirect-to-port-according-to-domain-prefix-dynamically)